# Is this the correct way of use Protocol, and if it's why mypy fails?

Tags: python, mypy

I have the following two classes:

```
@runtime_checkable
class AbstractFolder(Protocol):
    def __iter__(self) -> "AbstractFolder":
        raise NotImplementedError

    def __next__(self) -> AbstractFileReadable:
        raise NotImplementedError
```

and their implementation:

```
class FileSystemFolder(AbstractFolder, Iterator):
    def __init__(self, path: str):
        self.path: str = path

    def __iter__(self) -> "FileSystemFolder":
        self.jobs: List[AbstractFileReadable] = [
            FileSystemFileReadable(path)
            for path in [*glob(os.path.join(self.path, "*"))]
        ]
        self.current: int = -1
        return self

    def __next__(self) -> FileSystemFileReadable:
        self.current += 1

        if self.current >= len(self.jobs):
            raise StopIteration

        return self.jobs[self.current]
```

and the following function

```
def process(folder: AbstractFolder) -> None:
...
```

The children are returning instances of the implementation, which could be a lot, but when I execute mypy I get the following error:

```
error: Incompatible return value type (got "AbstractFileReadable", expected "FileSystemFileReadable")
```

Is this the correct way to implement and use Protocol and typing?

Thanks

Comment: You could make `AbstractFolder` generic in `__next__` return type with `AbstractFileReadable` as upper bound, and use this type variable to annotate `jobs` content. Also, just in your exact case you could just remove `self.jobs` annotation (or use explicit `list[FileSystemFileReadable]`, which is the same as inferred). Finally, I don't really understand why not return a generator from `__iter__`, removing `current` and `jobs` completely and greatly simplifying the implementation - is there some more complex logic behind that, removed from MRE?

Comment: (and I wonder why not cast `path` to `pathlib.Path` in `__init__` to get rid of `glob` and `os.path`, but it's not about your actual question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typing error that `mypy` is detecting has nothing to do with your use of `Protocol`. Rather, it's a conflict between the type of `self.jobs` (which is defined in `__iter__`) and the return value from `__next__`.

Despite the code only loading instances of `FileSystemFileReadable` into the `self.jobs` list, its type is hinted as `List[AbstractFileReadable]`, so theoretically, some other code could add a different type of object to it without violating the type declarations. When you take values out of the list, in `__next__`, you are returning them, and the return type is annotated as `FileSystemFileReadable`, but `mypy` thinks the list could contain the wider abstract type.

The solution to this is to change one of the annotations. Probably `self.jobs` should be hinted as `List[FileSystemFileReadable]`. Less likely, `__next__` should return the looser `AbstractFileReadable`, just like the protocol does.

On another note, unrelated to the type hinting problem you were asking about, it's probably bad form for `__iter__` to be doing the heavy lifting to set up the iteration in your code. A better idea would be to do it in `__init__`, while `__iter__` has just `return self` as its entire body. With the current implementation, an idiom like this will not work as expected:

```
f = FileSystemFolder("some/path")

first = next(f) # get one value for special processing
rest = list(f)  # put the rest of the values in a list
```

With your code, the first element yielded by the iterator will appear in `rest` along with all the others, since the `__iter__` call made by the `list` constructor will reset the iteration to the start.